# Как менять вид проведения документа по регистру с помощью реквизита в 1с?

Tags: 1с

Как сделать так чтобы меняя реквизит типа Булево, менялся вид проведения документа по регистру. Например, при проведение первой записи на скриншоте происходил расход, а при проведение записи второй записи происходил приход. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А для чего? Какая итоговая цель? Это же приходная накладная, она по логике должна только приходовать, прибавлять.

Comment: @Sagittarius на самом деле это условное название, просто самое задание звучить как: В документ «Приходная накладная» добавить реквизит типа «Булево», который будет отвечать за вид проведения документа по регистру (приход или расход).

Comment: Странное задание...

Comment: А у вам вообще на данный момент движения реализованы?

Comment: @Sagittarius да, реализованы, но в рамках теста как это работает

Comment: Тогда просто надо в зависимости от значения переменной менять вид движения

Comment: @Sagittarius в этом и вопрос, нужно сделать так чтобы при смене значения типа булева менялся вид проведения.

Answer (score 2):

Назвать реквизит, например - "ЭтоПриход". В обработчике проведения что-то вроде:

```
...
Движение.ВидДвижения = ?(ЭтоПриход, ВидДвиженияНакопления.Приход, ВидДвиженияНакопления.Расход);
...
```